# C++/CX: Why doesn't returning a StringReference work like passing one as an argument?

Tags: string, windows-runtime, c++-cx

`Platform::StringReference` exists so that you can pass a `const wchar_t*` across the ABI boundary to a function accepting a `String^` without making a copy.  The `StringReference` implicitly converts to a `String^` whose internal pointer matches the original `const wchar_t*`.  This is verified by the following code; if you step through it you find that `pz == z`:

```
void param(String^ s)
{
    const wchar_t* z = s->Data();
}

App::App()
{
    std::wstring p = L"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const wchar_t* pz = p.c_str();
    param(StringReference(pz));
}
```

However, trying to return a `StringReference` doesn't seem to work the same way and I'm curious why.  If I have a function that returns `String^` and I return a `StringReference` from it then the same implicit conversion operator is called, but when the caller gets their `String^` it has a different internal data pointer that contains a copy.  Here's some code that tries it:

```
String^ ret()
{
    std::wstring s = L"12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
    const wchar_t* z = s.c_str();
    return StringReference(z);
}

App::App()
{
    String^ r = ret();
    const wchar_t* rz = r->Data();
}
```

That code verifies in two ways: first, if you step through you'll find that `z != rz` and second, `r` ends up pointing to a valid string rather than garbage, so a copy must have been made because the original string is freed at the end of `ret`.

I also tried returning via out parameter, but I get the same results as a straight return (`z != oz` and `o` ends up with a valid string):

```
void out(String^* r)
{
    std::wstring s = L"12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
    const wchar_t* z = s.c_str();
    *r = StringReference(z);
}

App::App()
{
    String^ o;
    out(&o);
    const wchar_t* oz = o->Data();
}
```

Is there a way to return a `StringReference` across the ABI boundary in the same way that you can pass one?  I imagine the behavior would depend on the language of the caller and how that language marshals strings from WinRT, but it seems like at least a C++/CX caller ought to be able to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't return a StringReference across the ABI boundary.  Returning a StringReference across the ABI boundary is similar (but not identical) to returning the address of a local variable.  That's because the whole point of a StringReference is that the StringReference doesn't allocate any new memory.

Consider what would happen if you could return a StringReference across the ABI boundary.  What would happen if you had:

```
String^ ReturnAString()
{
    const wchar_t buffer[500] = "MyString";
    return StringReference(buffer);
}
```

The `StringReference` is just a wrapper around the stack allocated `buffer`.  And clearly you can't return that across the ABI boundary (the stack storage is reclaimed as soon as the routine exits).

Instead you need to return a real Platform::String - a Platform::String contains a copy of the string data and thus it can safely be returned to the caller.

Comment: Yeah, I get that my example is doing bad things by returning freed memory, but that was one way that I could confirm that a copy was occurring.  I do have a real use case for this which would return a reference to memory whose lifetime is controllable by the caller.  The ability to shoot yourself in the foot with a feature isn't necessarily a compelling reason to not support it, especially in C++.  I could understand higher-level languages not wanting to expose that level of complexity, but couldn't that be an implementation detail of their WinRT projection?

Comment: The problem here is that Platform::String requires an allocation.  But if you're just providing a string to a method, you don't want the additional overhead of a memory allocation/free/copy. That's where StringReference comes in.

C++/CX is for people who want to code close to the metal - in environments where an extra allocation makes a difference.  The StringReference type exists to facilitate that scenario (calling into APIs which require a string parameter but where you don't want to allocate and copy memory).

Comment: I do understand what `StringReference` is for, I just wish that I could use it to retrieve strings from a component as efficiently as I can pass them to one.  Thanks much for a definitive answer that it is not currently possible, I'm just trying to understand why.  Is it a technical problem, a design decision?  Is it just because returning references is potentially more perilous?  Is it not worth the time to optimize yet?  It seems like it should be technically feasible at least for C++/CX calls into C++/CX components, and other projections could continue to always copy strings.

Comment: It's a technical reason - StringReference does not allocate memory, nor does it take ownership of the memory it references. Instead it takes memory that is owned by another object (in your example a std::wstring object) and presents it to another function. The lifetime management of that memory remains with the owning object.  As such if you were to be able to return the StringReference, the memory would be freed when the std::wstring goes out of scope. If you want a string value that can be returned, use Platform::String, which manages the lifetime of its own memory.

Comment: Again, I understand how it works and why my example is bad; I wrote it that way on purpose. Surely it's not too hard to imagine a case where a ref class instance owns some (perhaps a lot of) very large strings and would like to efficiently allow callers to access them, with the understanding that the destruction of that instance will also invalidate any of the accessed strings. The reason you cite is effectively "this feature isn't implemented because you can shoot yourself in the foot with it". I guess that's a valid reason, but I hope the benefits make it worth implementing some day anyway.

Comment: Remember that Platform::StringReference is a wrapper around WindowsCreateStringReference (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br224631(v=vs.85).aspx), it might be possible to use that to manage such a ref class.